# Optimization tips for reading/parsing large number of JSON.gz files

Tags: python, json

I have an interesting problem at hand. As someone who's a beginner when it comes to working with data at even a morderate scale, I'd love some tips from the veterans here.

I have around `6000` Json.gz files totalling around 5GB compressed and 20GB uncompressed.
I'm opening each file and reading them line by line using the `gzip` module; then using `json.loads()` loading each line and parsing the complicated JSON structure. Then I'm inserting lines from each file into a Pytable all at once before iterating to the next file.

All this is taking me around 3 hours. Bulk inserting into the Pytable didn't really help the speed at all. Much of the time is gone getting values from the parsed JSON line since they have a truly horrible structure. Some are straightforward like `'attrname':attrvalue`, but some are complicated and time consuming structures like:

`'attrarray':[{'name':abc, 'value':12},{'value':12},{'name':xyz, 'value':12}...]`

...where I need to pick up the `value` of all those objects in the `attr` array which have some corresponding `name`, and ignore those that don't. So I need to iterate through the list and inspect each JSON object inside. (I'd be glad if you can point out any quicker clever way, if it exists)

So I suppose the actual parsing part of it doesn't have much scope of speedup. Where I think their *might* be scope of speedup is the actual reading the file part.

So I ran a few tests (I don't have the numbers with me right now) and even after removing the parsing part of my program; simply going through the files line by line *itself* was taking a considerable amount of time.

So I ask: Is there any part of this problem that you think I might be doing suboptimally?

```
for filename in filenamelist:
    f = gzip.open(filename):
    toInsert=[]
    for line in f:
        parsedline = json.loads(line)
        attr1 = parsedline['attr1']
        attr2 = parsedline['attr2']
        .
        .
        .
        attr10 = parsedline['attr10']
        arr = parsedline['attrarray']
        for el in arr:
            try:
                if el['name'] == 'abc':
                    attrABC = el['value']
                elif el['name'] == 'xyz':
                    attrXYZ = el['value']
                .
                .
                .
            except KeyError:
                pass
        toInsert.append([attr1,attr2,...,attr10,attrABC,attrXYZ...])

    table.append(toInsert)
```

Comment: please include the output of the profiler

Comment: The problem could be gzip module. There are some alternatives here: http://aripollak.com/pythongzipbenchmarks/

Comment: When you say that reading takes considerable amount of time, that includes two costs already, that of IO and that of uncompressing. Be sure that you find out which of these takes how much time. After that, parsing and handling the lines is a third thing. All three of them could be parallelized to make better use of modern computers. Lastly, if you have multiple lines that each can be parsed as JSON, the overall file is not JSON. Or is it perhaps that the file only contains a single line? This might make a difference to parsing, at least it seems strange.

Answer (score 3):

## One clear piece of "low-hanging fruit"

If you're going to be accessing the same compressed files over and over (it's not especially clear from your description whether this is a one-time operation), then you should decompress them once rather than decompressing them on-the-fly each time you read them.

Decompression is a CPU-intensive operation, and [Python's `gzip` module is not that fast](http://codebright.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/139/) compared to C utilities like `zcat`/`gunzip`.

Likely the fastest approach is to `gunzip` all these files, save the results somewhere, and then read from the uncompressed files in your script.

## Other issues

The rest of this is not really an answer, but it's too long for a comment. In order to make this faster, you need to think about a few other questions:

1. What are you trying to **do** with all this data?
2. Do you really need to load **all** of it at once?

   - If you can segment the data into smaller pieces, then you can reduce the latency of the program if not the overall time required. For example, you might know that you only need a few specific lines from specific files for whatever analysis you're trying to do... great! Only load those specific lines.
   - If you **do** need to access the data in arbitrary and unpredictable ways, then you should load it into another system (RDBMS?) which stores it in a format that is more amenable to the kinds of analyses you're doing with it.

If the last bullet point is true, one option is to load each JSON "document" into a PostgreSQL 9.3 database (the [JSON support is awesome](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.3#JSON:_Additional_functionality) and [fast](http://www.reddit.com/comments/1q3skb)) and then do your further analyses from there. Hopefully you can extract meaningful keys from the JSON documents as you load them.